# Installing headers using automake

Tags: c++, autotools, automake

I'm writing a library which uses autotools for compiling/installing. My directory tree is kinda like this

```
/src/
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
/include/
    dir/
        header1.hpp
        header2.hpp
        subdir/
            header.hpp
configure.ac
Makefile.am
```

And I want to install the headers in `include/subdir/*` in `$(includedir)/subdir/`. How do I do that? And no, recursive makefiles are not an option. Recursive Make Considered Harmful.
http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
subdirheadersdir = $(includedir)/subdir
subdirheaders_HEADERS = include/subdir/header.hpp
```

Note that you cannot use wildcards (like `include/subdir/*.hpp`). You have to list all files. Also, `subdirheaders` is just an example name. You can use whatever you want.